# Get tweet id using ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am building an app to share a post on twitter using tweet button provided by twitter developers.On clicking the tweet button a new window open in which we can modify our tweet.There is one more tweet button on the new window.on clicking it our content gets tweeted. now I want to get id of the current tweet.It is shown in the url but i am unable to catch it in controller or in my database.Can any one help to sort this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to access it through the `params` hash. In your controller, you can get the id by using `params[:id]`

Comment: Unable to catch using params[:id] as a new seperate window is open.